# Create c# SelectList Without specifying values

Tags: c#, .net-core, selectlist

When manually creating a select list I normally have both text & value:

```
SelectList SupplierStatusList = new SelectList(new[] {
            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "Please Select", Value = "Please Select" },
            new SelectListItem { Selected = true, Text = "1", Value = "1" },
            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "2", Value = "2" },
            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "3", Value = "3" },
            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "4", Value = "4" },
            }, "Value", "Text");
```

But how do I do this without having to specify the value? This leaves the values = "" which I don't want.

```
SelectList SupplierStatusList = new SelectList(new[] {
            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "Please Select"},
            new SelectListItem { Selected = true, Text = "1"},
            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "2"},
            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "3"},
            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "4"},
            }, "Value", "Text");
```

Any ideas?

Sorry, to be clear yes I would like the text and value to be the same.

Comment: So what you expect to have if you will not specify `Value`?

Comment: Only specify `Value`, not `Text`?

Comment: `This leaves the values = "" which I don't want.` <-- if you don't want the default value, then _do_ specify one.

Comment: Do you mean you want the value to be same as the text?

Comment: Think the OP wants the value/text to be same

Comment: Havent used select list but there is a constructor overload taking in IEnumerable and Object (selected value), pretty sure if you just give a 1-D array in IEnumerable then it should work as expected https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_System_Object_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can use a constructor overload:

```
var selectListItems = new[] {"Please Select", "1", "2", "3"};
var selectList = new SelectList(selectListItems, "1");
```